# Как сделать задержку в setTimeout как переменную, результат функции

Tags: javascript, settimeout

Задача заключается в том, что найден кратчайший путь между точками a и с, и нужно чтобы по пути в консоль возвращалось "прибыл в такую то точку в такое то время", и задержка должна быть расстояние*1 секунду. В приведенном коде задержка почему-то всегда 1 секунда, умножения не происходит

```js
const ab = 1;
const bd = 2;
const bc = 3;
const dc = 4;

if (bd < bc) {
    const korotki1 = ab + bd + dc
    console.log('кратчайший путь a-b-d-c длиной', korotki1)
    function checkPoint1Ab() {
        console.log('доехал до точки b в', Date())
    }
    setTimeout(checkPoint1Ab, ab * 1000)
    function checkPoint1Bd() {
        console.log('доехал до точки d в', Date())
    }
    setTimeout(checkPoint1Bd, bd * 1000)
    function checkPoint1Dc() {
        console.log('доехал до точки c в', Date())
    }
    setTimeout(checkPoint1Dc, dc * 1000)
}
```

Comment: Пока не понятно чему равны твои переменные...

Comment: @ksa, ну например расстояния ab=1, bd=2, dc=3, у нас допустим машина движется со скоростью 1 расстояние в секунду, значит надо чтобы через 1 секунду было "прибытие в точку b", через еще 2 секунды "прибытие в точку d", и еще через 3 "прибытие в точку c"

Comment: Я добавил переменные в ваш код, что бы он был воспроизводимым и там все работает как вы и указали. ПРоверьте